# Simple regression linreg error in R: argument 'modeltest'must be either TRUE or FALSE

Tags: r, regression

Hello everyone I am having an issue with my R software. When I try to run a simple regression i get this error:

> model1 <- linReg(data = dat, dep = 'Intent', blocks = list(c('Enjoy')), modelTest = 'f', stdEst = TRUE)
> model1
> Error: Argument 'modelTest' must be either TRUE or FALSE

I have tried changing the  to a capital and typing in FALSE instead but when I type in FALSE I get this error:

> model1 <- linReg(data = dat, dep = 'Intent', blocks = list(c('Enjoy')), modelTest = FALSE, stdEst = TRUE)
> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'XRW5qb3k' not found

Can anyone please help me with this? All o the descriptives, graphs, and plots run just fine. I have the packages jmv, psych, and car loaded

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello Cara, welcome to SO. I'll do my best to help out but I won't be able to unless I can repeat the error on my computer. Can you create a reproducible example? There is a helpful guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ``` r
model1 <- linReg(data = dat, dep = "Desire", blocks = list(c("Enjoy")), 
    modelTest = "f", stdEst = TRUE)
#> Error in linReg(data = dat, dep = "Desire", blocks = list(c("Enjoy")), : could not find function "linReg"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Is that right???? I am confused why it says it could not ind function linreg in this one.